# How to check many to many relation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

I have a problem in checking if there is a conversation with the same members or not.

I have the `conversations (id, user_creator_id)` and `conversation_user (conversation_id, user_id)` table.

I have this model:

```
class Conversation extends Model
{
    public function ConversationUser() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ConversationUser', 'conversation_id' ,'id');
    }
```

In Controller I am trying using this function :

```
$ids = $this->collectUsersIds();
$same_conversation = Conversation::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
->whereHas('ConversationUser', function($q) use($ids)
{$q->whereIn('user_id', $ids);}, '=', count($ids))
->get();
```

But I didn't get the proper results I want when creating a new chat, to check whether there are the same members of the conversation or not.

Comment: Conversation::with('ConversationUser')->get();

Comment: then ? what is the best practice to check if i have the same member in the chat or not !

Comment: concersation X ,,,, ConversationUser return ( 1, 2 , 3) , what is the best way to make sure if we have it exists or not ! i am trying using whereHas() ,,, but its not working !